# Using awk with multiple pipings

Tags: bash, awk

The command

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe -group tuevGroup | grep mis.merchantCtpCredential
```

produces the following output without the header:

```
GROUP           TOPIC                      PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                HOST                      CLIENT-ID
tuevGroup       mis.merchantCtpCredentials 1          231             231             0               consumer-tuevGroup-2-00e2ed7d-0fdc-4303-bc06-0e8f50b1dc00  00.24.242.16/00.24.242.00 consumer-tuevGroup-2
tuevGroup       mis.merchantCtpCredentials 5          182             182             0               consumer-tuevGroup-2-00e2ed7d-0fdc-4303-bc06-0e8f50b1dc00  00.24.242.16/00.24.242.00 consumer-tuevGroup-2
```

I want to get the total number of LAG column for all rows, so I pipe the result to awk as follows

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe -group tuevGroup |
  grep mis.merchantCtpCredentials |
  awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}'
```

This however doesn't work, although If I commit the `grep mis.merchantCtpCredential` I get total result for all rows, unfiltered however

I am wondering what am I doing wrong here, your help is highly appreciated

Comment: `LAG` is in column 6, so you should be doing `sum += $6`.

Comment: ... and the total of that column as shown will be `0`.

Comment: Thanks, I though it was zero based. that was the right answer

Comment: `$0` in `awk` refers to the entire record.

Comment: Also, `grep ... | awk ...` is suboptimal. Instead, omit `grep` and use `awk '/mis.merchantCtpCredential {sum += $6} END {print sum}'`

Comment: Thanks Jim, this works adding additional / at the end of the topic name

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the help of @unxnut, @JimL, and @camh, my command had two problems:

1. I was referring to the wrong column (i.e $5 instead of $6).
2. The command is suboptimal, as the usage of grep was redundant in the first  place and can be replaced by a single awk call.

The final version of the command would hence be

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe -group tuevGroup | awk '$2 == "mis.merchantCtpCredential" {sum += $6} END {print sum+0}'
```